# Getting count of occurrence of a value in a column but ignoring double entries

Tags: mysql

I have a table with jobs number and its failure code (and of course much more information which is not used here).
Each job can be multiple times in the table with same failure code.

```
create table jobs
(
  id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  number int,
  failure int
);

insert into jobs (number, failure) VALUES 
  (1,1),(1,1),
  (2,2),(2,2),(2,2),
  (3,2),(3,2),
  (4,2),(4,2),(4,2),(4,2),
  (5,1)
```

What I need as final output is the number of jobs which have a failure of 1, 2, 3 etc but not counting double job numbers.
So the output for the above sample should be

failure - count

1 - 2

2 - 3

but I have no approach at the moment. I can only use mysql5.7 no 8.

Here is the fiddle with the data.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/924ced/2

Comment: your data sample is not clear to me .. try explain better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want avoid duplicated  values you could try count the distinct values

```
    select failure, count(*)
    from (
      select  distinct number, failure
      from  jobs
      ) t
      GROUP BY failure
```

Comment: Sometimes it is so easy but you didn't see it. .thanks a lot